# Remove elements completely if the all of their values are blank in the entire array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$arr = [
    [
        'RecordCount' => 1938,
        'CardNumber' => null,
        'CompanyID' => null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26
    ],
    [
        'RecordCount' => 2622,
        'CardNumber' => 5786,
        'CompanyID' =>null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26
    ],
    [
        'RecordCount' => 2874,
        'CardNumber' => 2874,
        'CompanyID' =>null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26    
    ]
];
```

Is there a function that will remove companyID and RecordRequest from the array completely because their values are blank throughout the entire array? It will keep cardNumber because it is not blank throughout the entire array. 
Returning:

```
[0] => Array(
    [RecordCount] => 1938
    [CardNumber] => null
    [RecordStatus] => 26
)
[1] => Array(
    [RecordCount] => 2622
    [CardNumber] => 5786
    [RecordStatus] => 26
)
[2] => Array(
    [RecordCount] => 2874
    [CardNumber] => 6875
    [RecordStatus] => 26
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no built-in functions to do this, but this should work (ps! written for php >= 7.1):

```
function remove_always_nulls(Iterable &$it)
{
    // dictionary of keys to keep (because they were non-null at some point)
    $keep_dict=array();
    $inner=function(Iterable $it)use(&$inner,&$keep_dict){
    foreach ($it as $key => $val) {
        if (is_iterable($val)) {
            $keep_dict[$key]=true;
            $inner($val);
        } elseif (!is_null($val)) {
            $keep_dict[$key]=true;
        }
    }
    };
    $inner($it);
    $remover=function(Iterable &$it_remove) use(&$remover,&$keep_dict){
        foreach($it_remove as $key=>&$val){
            if(is_iterable($val)){$remover($val);}elseif(!($keep_dict[$key]??false)){unset($it_remove[$key]);}
        }
    };
    $remover($it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_map`.

it will call a function for each element in the array.

in the function, create a temporary array that will hold the values that are not empty and returns that temporary array as the result in that iteration.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
        'RecordCount' => 1938,
        'CardNumber' => 4093,
        'CompanyID' => null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26
    ],
    [
        'RecordCount' => 2622,
        'CardNumber' => 5786,
        'CompanyID' =>null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26
    ],
    [
        'RecordCount' => 2874,
        'CardNumber' => 2874,
        'CompanyID' =>null,
        'RecordRequest' =>null,
        'RecordStatus' => 26    
    ]
];


$res = array_map(function($subarr) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($subarr as $key=>$val) {
        if(!empty($val)) {
            $tmp[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $tmp;

},$arr);

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I updated my poorly asked question. Notice now that the first cardNumber is now null but has values elsewhere in the array. Your answer removes every blank element. I only want to remove the element if it is blank throughout the entire array.